# Vote to close bounty question - example code

Tags: discussion, status-completed, specific-question, vote-to-close, bounty

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/87366/unit-testing-ui-related-modules

> A module + test could look something like this:
>
> ```
>    var uiModule = (function($){
>
>    function init(){
>         getData().done(function(data){
>             addResultToUi();
>             bindEvents();
>         });
>     }
>
>    function getData(){
>         return $.ajax({ url: 'something' });
>     }
>
>    function addResultToUi(data){
>         $('.dummy').append('<p>' + data.text + '</p>')
>     }
>
>    function bindEvents(){
>         $('.dummy').on('click', function(){
>             $(this).text('blah');
>         });
>     }
>
>    return {
>         init: init 
>     };
>
> })(jQuery);
> ```
>
> ```
> function setup(){
>     uiModule.init();
> }
>
> function tearDown(){
>     uiModule = null;
> }
>
> test('data text added to dummy element', function(assert){
>      var result = $('.dummy > p').text();
>      assert.ok(result.length > 0);
> });
>
> test('click on dummy sets text to blah', function(assert){
>      var $dummy = $('.dummy');
>      $dummy.trigger('click');
>      assert.equal('foo', $dummy.text());
> });
> ```

That looks like example code to me.

I think it would be best if the bounty was refunded and the question closed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree with you. See this relevant information in the question :

> A module + test could look something like this

This is a clear indicator that it is not real code but example code. I think we should refund and close the question, if the user don't want to provide the real code and real tests. I think it could be on-topic if would be about real code.

Comment: Agreed. I've refunded the bounty and put the question on hold.

Comment: Should we custom-flag such bounty questions or treat them as 'normal' questions?

Comment: You can't close a question when there is a bounty on it. Only a mod can refund the bounty and close the question. So flagging is the way, not you sure you can cast close vote.